# I found a question that contains an answer that is weak and/or may be wrong. Should this question/answer be moderated somehow?

Tags: discussion

**I found a question that contains an answer that is weak and/or may be wrong. should this question/answer be moderated somehow?**

Here is the question I found:

[opensource.se: Is it allowed to dynamically link a GPL licensed library for commercial use?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/2157/is-it-allowed-to-dynamically-link-a-gpl-licensed-library-for-commercial-use)

Is there a duplicate of this question? If so, could the question be marked as duplicate?

(I couldn't find any duplicates by googling)

The reason I am saying the answer is weak and/or may be wrong is because I see a really strong answer over here by an author with lots of SE points/history/experience:

[softwareenginnering.se: Can I link to a GPL library from a closed source application](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/158789/can-i-link-to-a-gpl-library-from-a-closed-source-application)

Comment: I can say in general, no, this not what moderation is for. SE's system handles weak or wrong answers (for better or worse) via popular vote. It is not the duty of moderators to validate the correctness of answers (except insofar as any user might, by comments and downvotes).

Comment: @apsillers the question is IMO a canonical question because (1.) asks something fundamental about the GPL (i.e. why the GPL was created in the first place) and the GPL is one of the most used open source licenses (2.) the question is in the center of opensource.se's mission statement **"for people producing, distributing, marketing and monetizing Free and Open projects."** so... i would expect opensource.se to have a good answer to this question... but i don't see a good question/answer for this... except this IMO extremely low quality answer... relative to the softwareengineering.se answer.

Comment: I'm not sure we are operating with the same definition of "strong answer" -- I see a well-sourced, broad overview of legal perspectives on dynamic linking versus an unsourced three-sentence answer on Software Engineering. The Open Source answer appears much better to me -- not to knock the Software Engineering answer; it is not incorrect, but to call it "much stronger" seems to use a different definition of "strong" than I use. I think it just such differences of opinion in answer quality that require moderators not to adjudicate answer quality.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not trying to pick a fight by any means, but highlight the parameters by which I evaluate answer quality. You clearly view the other site's answer as superior; I clearly view the answer on this site as superior.  I have no problem that we disagree on this, though I am curious by what parameters you arrived at so different a conclusion!

Comment: @apsillers re "what is good quality": i do agree. the other answer does not contain sources. and is too short IMO. so the shorter answer on softwareengineering.se while more correct... is not good/great quality. i guess my issue is that the longer answer on opensource.se does not give a clear concise conclusion and so is less correct... on a subject that IMO does have a clear concise answer and decades of legal precedent.

Comment: @apsillers the reason i'm posting all of this... is because i came to opensource.se hoping to get a better quality answer... better than the short softwareengineering.se answer... which doesn't have any sources and is provided on a site that can't vet his answer as good because softwareengineering.se's main purpose isn't to cover opensource/GPL questions.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith, what is your basis for stating that the answer on softwareengineering.se is more correct? To my knowledge there is no actual legal precedent (as in, a judge ruling in a court case) for how the GPL must be interpreted.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau re "[GPL has] no actual legal precedent (as in, a judge ruling in a court case)": i'm not an expert. that's why i'm asking the question here. this question is important and in the wheelhouse of this SE... but doesn't provide a good quality answer IMO. the softwareengineering.se answer is also weak because it is short and lacks citations but that type of question is not in their wheelhouse... so again i come here expecting a better answer...

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to give a specific answer since you linked the same questions twice (presumably by mistake), but if you think an answer is wrong, you could (should?) downvote it.